# Sticky header on SectionList ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview, react-native-sectionlist

I need to create a screen Catalog(Categories and Products).
I'm using SectionList from React Native in order to achive this.

I need to make that Categories component stick on the top when you scroll product lists.
Is there any library that could help me with this Catalog screen ?
[Please look at the image here..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuMUt.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, SectionList } from "react-native";

import Text from "../Text";

const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Main dishes",
    data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"],
  },
  {
    title: "Sides",
    data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"],
  },
  {
    title: "Drinks",
    data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"],
  },
  {
    title: "Desserts",
    data: ["Cheese Cake", "Ice Cream"],
  },
];

const TabCategories = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Horizontal list of categories</Text>
  </View>
);

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const TestSectionList = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.SRC}>Some React Component</Text>
      <SectionList
        sections={DATA}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
          <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
        )}
        StickyHeaderComponent={TabCategories}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  SRC: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#fff",
    padding: 10,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 30,
  },
  header: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

export default TestSectionList;
```

Answer (score 7):

`stickySectionHeadersEnabled`
Makes section headers stick to the top of the screen until the next one pushes it up

`ListHeaderComponent`
Rendered at the very beginning of the list

`renderSectionHeader`
Rendered at the top of each SECTION

I think this should do:

```
<SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
      ListHeaderComponent={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
      )}
      renderSectionHeader={TabCategories}
      stickySectionHeadersEnabled
   />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library `react-native-tabs-section-list`

https://github.com/bogoslavskiy/react-native-tabs-section-list

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [react-native-section-list](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist), it inherits ScrollView props, you can check in the docs, in props section, so it has [stickyHeaderComponent prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#props) which should be exactly what you want.

Comment: Could you please update your question with some code snippet.

Comment: Ok. now header is rendered for every section and its not sticky.

Comment: Yeah, seems like that doesn't work yet, the only workaround i see is just add another component next to ```Some React Component``` that you have, above your ```SectionList```, might as well open new issue on GitHub...

Comment: Well.. I will keep just 1 component(Categories component), both components takes alot of space. Thanks